# Sort an entire row using excel VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, row

I am creating a client register where clients can be added using a button. I also have a sort function that allows me to sort them on **klantnr**. But the problem is whenever I use the sort function it only sorts **klantnr** and the added information provided from the form keeps in place. For example, this is my userform:

(http://puu.sh/cw94k/ebf4510a24.png)

And this is my excel sheet:

(http://puu.sh/cw9nc/3a8e19a989.png)

When I add another row it sorts **klantnr** but it doesn't take the other values, such as **Naam** and **Adres** with it. So it needs to sort **klantnr** and take the other information with it

This is my code:

```
Private Sub btn_Toevoegen_Click()
   Dim laatsteKlantNummer As Integer

Range("B4:B13").End(xlDown).Select
laatsteKlantNummer = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = txtKlant + 0
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = txtNaam
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = txtAdres
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Value = txtWoonplaats
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4).Value = txtContact
Me.Hide
Range("B4:B13").Sort Key1:=Range("B4:B13"), Order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the Sort object of the sheet instead of the one from the range object:

```
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B4")
ActiveSheet.Sort.SetRange Range("B4:F13")
ActiveSheet.Sort.Apply
```

There you can use the SetRange method to define not only the key column but also the others you want to have sortet